# How to make this more Pythonic or readable for the future?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a string of multiple words connected with `_` (for example `hello_my_name_is_john_doe_good_day`). I want to take this string and convert it to look like `John Doe`.

I currently have

```
tempStr0 = "hello_my_name_is_john_doe_good_day"
tempStr1 = tempStr0.split("_")[4:6]
tempStr2 = (tempStr1[0][0].upper() + tempStr1[0][1:] + " " + tempStr1[1][0].upper() + tempStr1[1][1:])
print(tempStr2) 
# John Doe
```

This obviously does work but looks pretty ugly. Can anyone make some suggestions on how I might clean this up to make it more Pythonic and readable for the future?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `.title()` for the processing of individual substrings, and use `' '.join(..)` to join these together, like:

```
tempStr2 = ' '.join(sube.title() for sube in tempStr1)
```

this will *capitalize* every word. Since the subelements are probably individual words, we can use `.capitalize()` as well:

```
# alternative
tempStr2 = ' '.join(sube.capitalize() for sube in tempStr1)
```

The nice thing is that if `tempStr1` contains *multiple* elements, it will add these words as well, separated by a space.

Furthermore `.title()` and `.capitalize()` are also more safe than performing string operations manually: if the string is empty, then these will still work.